# Bootstrapping t-test

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, bootstrap

Consider two independent random samples **x** and **y** with different sample sizes m and n (with m much larger than n).
I wish to:

1. determine whether the mean of **y** is significantly different than the mean of **x**
2. determine whether the standard deviation of **y** is significantly different than the standard deviation of **x**
3. potentially, determine whether any arbitrary statistic s(**y**) is significanty different from s(**x**)
4. achieve all of this using some form of bootstrapping/subsampling

I know I can achieve 1. using bootstrap-based statistical testing (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Bootstrap_hypothesis_testing)). However, I am not sure how to achieve 2 and 3. Something that I thought of:

- draw a few thousands of random samples with replacement from **x** of size n (I guess a form of m out of n bootstrapping)
- calculate the standard deviation of each of these samples and plot them as an (approximately normal) curve
- calculate the standard deviation of **y** and compare it against the bootstrapped samples by calculating p-values in a similar way as for the standard bootstrap-based t-test (see link above)

I am wondering if this second method makes sense or if there's better ways of doing this. What is spooking me is that in this second approach I am sampling with replacement but the size of the bootstrap sample is smaller than the size of **x**, which from my understanding you're not supposed to do.

Comment: Are you sure you know how to achieve 1? If you are fitting a normal distribution to a bootstrapped sample as you propose in 2, you are undoing any benefit of having bootstrapped in the first place.

Comment: @AdamO well 1. I can achieve with the standard boostrapping statistical testing method (see the wiki link in the post) which is a well established approach. The question is about how to achieve 2 and 3 here.